# If there is a constant in the solution to an ODE is that assumed to be the initial condition?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = e^t \sin(y)$$

and Wolfram Alpha gives the solution as

$$y(t) = 2\cot^{-1}(e^{c_1 - e^t})$$

Why is it giving me some unknown constant $c_1$ with no mention of what it is? Is it assumed that this is $y_0$, the initial condition?

Comment: This is an example of an 'integration constant', corresponding to the fact that finding the solution of such an ODE often amounts to computing an indefinite integral. It is generally not identical to the initial condition(s), but it is _determined_ by them.

Comment: You can force WA by adding `y(0)=a` to the request to incorporate the initial condition in the solution. and indeed, the request `y'(t)=exp(t)*sin(y(t)), y(0)=a` gives as solution $y(t) = 2 \cot^{-1}(e^{1-e^t} \cot(\frac a2))$.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$y_0=y(0)= 2\cot^{-1}(e^{c_1 - e^0})$$

hence

$$c_1=\ln\left(\cot\left(\frac{y_0}2\right)\right)+1.$$

Comment: Thanks. Strange that Wolfram Alpha doesn't give you this info

Comment: @jphollowed: did you provide the initial condition ? If not, Alpha is innocent.

Comment: @jphollowed: Try [this `y'(t)=exp(t)*sin(y(t)), y(0)=a`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28t%29%3Dexp%28t%29*sin%28y%28t%29%29,+y%280%29%3Da)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not $y(0)$.  $y(0) = 2 \cot^{-1}(e^{c_1 - 1})$.